# How do I change the data attributes of child elements in a loop using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I have a sortable list created using KendoUI for MVC.  This list works fine and I've been working on the reordering of the data-attributes so that when you reorder the list, the attributes names still run sequentially.

```
<ul id="plot__points">
    <li class="sortable disabled" data-tag="plot0">
        <label>Location START</label>                
        <div class="plotrow lat" data-lat="lat_plot0">
            <input class="k-textbox" value="003" />
        </div>
        <div class="plotrow lon" data-lon="lon_plot0">
            <input class="k-textbox" value="004" />
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="sortable" data-tag="plot1">
        <label>Location #1</label>
        <div class="plotrow lat" data-lat="lat_plot1">
            <input class="k-textbox" value="001" />
        </div>
        <div class="plotrow lon" data-lon="lon_plot1">
            <input class="k-textbox" value="002" />
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="sortable" data-tag="plot2">
        <label>Location #2</label>
        <div class="plotrow lat" data-lat="lat_plot2">
            <input class="k-textbox" value="003" />
        </div>
        <div class="plotrow lon" data-lon="lon_plot2">
            <input class="k-textbox" value="004" />
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="sortable" data-tag="plot3">
        <label>Location #3</label>
        <div class="plotrow">
            <div class="plotrow lat" data-lat="lat_plot3">
                <input class="k-textbox" value="005" />
               </div>
            <div class="plotrow lon" data-lon="lon_plot3">
                <input class="k-textbox" value="007" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The kendoUI part of the code which follows the above HTML is:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Sortable()
    .For("#plot__points")
    .Cursor("url('" + Url.Content("~/content/web/sortable/grabbing.cur") + "'), default")
    .CursorOffset(offset => offset.Left(-230).Top(-10))
    .HintHandler("hint")
    .Disabled(".disabled")
    .Events(e => e.Change("onChange"))
    .PlaceholderHandler("placeholder")
)
```

As you can see there is a `data-attribute` set on every `li` as `data-tag`.  When you reorder the list the `data-tag` is updated so that they run sequentially.  This is achieved by the following javascript that runs on the event handler of `Change`.

```
function onChange(e) { 
    console.clear();        

    $("#plot__points > li").each(function(index, item) {
    $(this).attr("data-tag", "plot" + (index + 1));
    $(this).children('div[data-lat]').attr('data-lat', "lat_plot" + (index + 1));
    $(this).children('div[data-lon]').attr('data-lon', "lon_plot" + (index + 1));
  });
}
```

All this works fine but I want to also update the child elements `data-lat` and `data-lon` within each li to match their newly sorted `data-tag` number.  I have made an attempt to do this within the onChange function but it's not working as expected.  I have produced this JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/59cus1cL/1/ (converted to use jQuery version of KendoUI for the purposes od this demo).

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Can you create a DEMO of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nested items are not direct children of the `li` elements (`this`), so `children` will not find them.

Instead use `find`:

```
$(this).find('div[data-lat]').attr('data-lat', "lat_plot" + (index + 1));
```

Comment: Perfect! That worked, thank you.  I didn't realise that they had to be direct children.